# Activity not getting closed

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am working on an app where I am drawing my custom lockscreen (An Activity) over the system's default lock.

Everything is working perfectly fine except one thing, I am using a reciever and whenever there is an incoming call, that reciever gets called and from inside that reciever I am closing the activity.

**Note :  This is happening only in case of OnePlus device, on any other device it's working perfectly.**

```
private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        OverlayActivity overlayActivity = new OverlayActivity();
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // System.out.println("RINGING");
                overlayActivity.finish();
                // System.out.println("Activity has been closed!!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Both the lines before and after the code where I am closing the activity is working completely fine, but the activity is not getting closed.

Comment: can you put your code which is actuality finishes Activity

Comment: @ChetanJoshi "overlayActivity.finish();", this is the code which closes the activity.

Comment: You're creating new activity object and trying to call finish on it. It doesn't work like that. You need get hold of the activity reference which is showing on the screen and then call finish on it.

Comment: `OverlayActivity overlayActivity = new OverlayActivity();` you should **never** create an instance of activity. Only the system can create it. Also it makes totally no sense to finish the activity you have created and not shown.

Comment: @Samuel Robert It was exactly what you have mentioned. +1 for pointing out :)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks for poing out, its working like a charm now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And if you are creating Activity Object its not working at all you
>   needs and Actual Activity Object or Context of Activity to close it.

Comment: **And if you are creating Activity Object its not working at all you needs and Actual Activity Object or Context of Activity to close it.** This was the issue, i was creating a new instance of the activity and calling finish() on that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Kunal if my answer helpful for you then please upvote and accept it.

Comment: your partial answer was helpful, so if you could edit and remove rest of the part i will accept the answer.

Comment: @kunal i have removed first section of answer .